# PHP notice: Undefined index: idOrAttributeName_x

Tags: php, jquery, yii

**PHP notice: Undefined index: idOrAttributeName_x**

I am using jcrop extension in yii framework.At that time I got this notice.I am developing a website using yii framework in which I have a task to crop a image.For this task I am using Jcrop extension in yii framework. 
When I am adding below given code to my controller action index() method,then I got this error.Actually I dont know which variable to pass in the function.

```
Yii::import('ext.jcrop.EJCropper');
$jcropper = new EJCropper();
$jcropper->thumbPath = '/my/images/thumbs';

// some settings ...
$jcropper->jpeg_quality = 95;
$jcropper->png_compression = 8;

// get the image cropping coordinates (or implement your own method)
***$coords = $jcropper->getCoordsFromPost(**'idOrAttributeName'**);***

// returns the path of the cropped image, source must be an absolute path.
$thumbnail = $jcropper->crop('/my/images/imageToCrop.jpg', $coords);
```

I am new in yii framework please help...

Comment: Please provide a link to the extension

Comment: I've not used that extension before, but it looks like the method `getCoordsFromPost()` is looking for an attribute in your POST array. if you change `idOrAttributeName` to the name of the file you've posted that may help?

Answer (score 0):

ok, the thing is that jcropper will look for 'POST' values to detect where to do cropping (x, y, height and width). In order to provide them you have to send them encoded like
'somestring_x', 'somestring_y', 'somestring_h' and 'somestring_w'.

In this case 'somestring' is exactly what you put in the `getCoordsFromPost` method: in your case `"idOrAttributeName"`.

If you take a look at the sourcecode on [github](https://github.com/digitick/yii-jcrop/blob/master/EJCropper.php) it will be clear (it's indeed very simple).